# 8-year old male ancestor sailed alone from Liverpool to Philadelphia in 1840

Tags: england, immigration, pennsylvania, manifest, 1840s

The family always told us about Reuben sailing from Liverpool to Philadelphia in 1840 with his father, and being left in Philadelphia with his uncle to grow up in uncle's family, with the father returning to the Redditch area. But when I checked the passenger log of the his ship from Liverpool, no kin were with him. This was all back in 1840.

Was there a practice to entrust youngsters (esp boys) to the captain's care, or to another passenger?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.

Comment: Can you link us to the passenger log, so we can see if we interpret it the same as you?